# Showing the relation between Hessian matrix and positive semidefinite

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

The problem says:

> $\Delta_{k}$   is determinant of $k\times k$   matrix which is matrix
>   of Hessian with the last $n-k$   rows and colums removed. Let
>   $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  , and assume that for
>   some integer $k$  , $\Delta_{k}<0$  , where $\Delta_{k}$   is
>   evaluated at $x_{0}$  . Show that $f$   cannot have a local minimum at
>   $x_{0}$  .

So, using contraposition, i.e., it suffices to show that if $f$ has a local minimum at $x_0$, then $\Delta _k \geq 0$ for all $k$. Furthermore, I tried to show that  the consequence of what I want to show is equivalent to positive semi-definite using Sylvester's Criterion.

Edit : In my textbook, Hessian defined only a function in $C^2$. So, I can use f Sylvester's Criterion. Then how can I go?

Comment: I am sure that the problem assumes that $f\in C^2$. If it does not, it is highly probable that the person who wrote it simply forgot to add this assumption.

Comment: More important, $x_0$ should be an interior point.